# How to insert row at desired index in UITableView Xamarin.ios?

Tags: uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, nsindexpath

i want to add a couple of rows on the index next to the selected row index.
For example if i have clicked row at index 4 i want some rows to added at index 5,6,7. and the actual rows of these indexes shift forward on 8,9,10 etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your table view source `MyTableViewSource` you have to override `RowSelected`. In this method, you check your row number and add items to you table view source's `Items` after adding them, you have to call `ReloadData()`.

```cs
class MyTableViewSource : UITableViewSource
{
    private readonly UITableView _table;
    public List<string> Items { get; }

    public MyTableViewSource(UITableView table)
    {
        _table = table;
        Items = new List<string> { "Hello", "World", "Bla", "Foo" };
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var item = Items[indexPath.Row];
        var cell = // create cellfor item
        return cell;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return Items.Count;
    }

    public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        if (indexPath.Row == 2)
        {
            Items.Insert(3, "Horst");
            Items.Insert(4, "Klaus");
            Items.Insert(5, "Peter");
            _table.ReloadData();
        }
    }
}
```

Creating them:

```cs
var table = new UITableView();
table.Source = new MyTableViewSource(table);
```

If you want more control over the animation, you can use this version:

```cs
public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    if (indexPath.Row == 2)
    {
        _table.BeginUpdates();
        Items.Insert(3, "Horst");
        Items.Insert(4, "Klaus");
        Items.Insert(5, "Peter");

        _table.InsertRows(new[] { NSIndexPath.Create(0, 3), NSIndexPath.Create(0, 4), NSIndexPath.Create(0, 5) }, UITableViewRowAnimation.Left);
        _table.EndUpdates();
    }
}
```

Comment: well that was helpful, thnx a lot.

Comment: If this answers your question, accept it as answer, so that it will not remain in the unanswered question lane. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: This was very useful for me, THANKS!!